# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout what to do here?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have checked out another post with the same title but it did not help me with my problem,so I am writing my problem here. I am getting this error and here is my code.
https://github.com/shobhitbehl98/Blockchain_Basic . Here is the link if you want to go through the full code but the relevant files with code are below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.blockchain_basic;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.blockchain_basic.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.databinding.ContentMainBinding;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.fragment.PowFragment;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.manager.BlockchainManager;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.manager.SharedPreferencesManager;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.model.BlockModel;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.utils.CipherUtils;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ContentMainBinding viewBindingContent;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferencesManager prefs;
    private BlockchainManager blockChain;
    private boolean isEncryptionActivated, isDarkActivated;
    private static final String TAG_POW_DIALOG="proof_of_work_dialog";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        prefs=new SharedPreferencesManager(this);
        isDarkActivated=prefs.isDarkTheme();
        PowerManager powerManager=(PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isPowerSaveMode=false;
        if(powerManager!=null){
            isPowerSaveMode=powerManager.isPowerSaveMode();
        }
        if(isPowerSaveMode){
            isPowerSaveMode=powerManager.isPowerSaveMode();
        }else{
            if(isDarkActivated){
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }else{
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityMainBinding viewBinding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        viewBindingContent=ContentMainBinding.bind(viewBinding.contentMain.getRoot());
        isEncryptionActivated=prefs.getEncryptionStatus();
        viewBindingContent.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        viewBindingContent.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        showProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.text_creating_block_chain));

        new Thread(()-> runOnUiThread(()->{
            blockChain=new BlockchainManager(prefs.getPowValue(),this);
            viewBindingContent.recyclerView.setAdapter(blockChain.adapter);
            cancelProgressDialog(progressDialog);
        })).start();
        viewBindingContent.btnSendData.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    private void startBlockChain(){
        showProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.text_mining_blocks));
        runOnUiThread(()->{
            if(blockChain!=null && viewBindingContent.editMessage.getText()!=null&&viewBindingContent.recyclerView.getAdapter()!=null){
               String message=viewBindingContent.editMessage.getText().toString();
               if(!message.isEmpty()){
                   if(!isEncryptionActivated){
                       blockChain.addBlock(blockChain.newBlock(message));
                   }else{
                       try{
                           blockChain.addBlock(blockChain.newBlock(CipherUtils.encryptIt(message).trim()));
                       }catch(Exception e){
                           e.printStackTrace();
                           Toast.makeText(this,"Something fishy happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }

                   viewBindingContent.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(blockChain.adapter.getItemCount()-1);
                   if(blockChain.isBlockChainValid()){
                       viewBindingContent.recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                       viewBindingContent.editMessage.setText("");
                   }else{
                       Toast.makeText(this,"BlockChain corrupted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(this,"Error empty data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               cancelProgressDialog(progressDialog);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Something wrong happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_send_data) {
            startBlockChain();
        }
    }



        private void showProgressDialog(@NonNull String loadingMessage){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setMessage(loadingMessage);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        private void cancelProgressDialog(@NonNull ProgressDialog progressDialog){
            if(progressDialog!=null){
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkEncrypt=menu.findItem(R.id.action_encrypt);
        checkEncrypt.setChecked(isEncryptionActivated);
        MenuItem checkTheme=menu.findItem(R.id.action_dark);
        checkTheme.setChecked(isDarkActivated);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_pow:
                PowFragment powFragment=PowFragment.newInstance();
                powFragment.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),TAG_POW_DIALOG);
                break;
            case R.id.action_encrypt:
                isEncryptionActivated= !item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(isEncryptionActivated);
                if(item.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Message Encryption ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Message Encryption OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                prefs.setEncryptionStatus(isEncryptionActivated);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_dark:
                isDarkActivated=!item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(isDarkActivated);
                prefs.setDarkMode(isDarkActivated);
                Intent intent=this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(this.getPackageName());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**BlockAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.blockchain_basic.adapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.R;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.model.BlockModel;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.viewholder.RecyclerViewHolder;
import java.util.List;

public class BlockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private List<BlockModel>blocks;
    private Context mcontext;
    private int lastPosition=-1;
    public BlockAdapter(@Nullable List<BlockModel> blocks, @NonNull Context mcontext) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtIndex.setText(String.format(mcontext.getString(R.string.title_block_number),blocks.get(position).getIndex()));
        holder.txtPreviousHash.setText(blocks.get(position).getPreviousHash()!=null?blocks.get(position).getPreviousHash():"Null");
        holder.txtTimeStamp.setText(blocks.get(position).getData());
        holder.txtHash.setText(blocks.get(position).getHash());
        setAnimation(holder.itemView,position);
    }

    private void setAnimation(View itemView, int position) {
        if(position>lastPosition){
            Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mcontext, android.R.anim.fade_in);
            itemView.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition=position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.item_block_data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blocks==null? 0:blocks.size();
    }
}
```

**BlockChainManager.java**

```
package com.example.blockchain_basic.manager;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.blockchain_basic.adapter.BlockAdapter;
import com.example.blockchain_basic.model.BlockModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BlockchainManager {
    private int difficulty;
    private List<BlockModel> blocks;
    public final BlockAdapter adapter;

    public BlockchainManager(int difficulty, @NonNull Context context) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        blocks=new ArrayList<>();
        BlockModel block=new BlockModel(0,System.currentTimeMillis(),null,"Genesis Block");
        block.mineBlock(difficulty);
        blocks.add(block);
        adapter=new BlockAdapter(blocks,context);
    }

    public BlockModel newBlock(String data){
        BlockModel latestBlock=latestBlock();
        return new BlockModel(latestBlock.getIndex()+1,System.currentTimeMillis(),latestBlock.getHash(),data);
    }
    private BlockModel latestBlock(){
        return blocks.get(blocks.size()-1);
    }

    public void addBlock(BlockModel block){
        if(block!=null){
            block.mineBlock((difficulty));
            blocks.add(block);
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirstBlockValid(){
        BlockModel firstBlock=blocks.get(0);
        if(firstBlock.getIndex()!=0){
            return false;
        }

        if(firstBlock.getPreviousHash()!=null){
            return false;
        }

        return firstBlock.getHash()!=null && BlockModel.calculateHash_detail(firstBlock).equals(firstBlock.getHash());
    }

    private boolean isValidNewBlock(@Nullable BlockModel newBlock,@Nullable BlockModel previousBlock) {
        if (newBlock != null && previousBlock != null) {
            if (previousBlock.getIndex() + 1 != newBlock.getIndex()) {
                return false;
            }


            if (newBlock.getPreviousHash() == null || !newBlock.getPreviousHash().equals(newBlock.getData())) {
                return false;
            }
            return newBlock.getHash() != null && BlockModel.calculateHash_detail(newBlock).equals(newBlock.getHash());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isBlockChainValid(){
        if(!isFirstBlockValid()){
            return false;
        }

        for(int i=1;i<blocks.size();i++){
            BlockModel currentBlock=blocks.get(i);
            BlockModel previousBlock=blocks.get(i-1);
            if(!isValidNewBlock(currentBlock,previousBlock)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it creating any problem?

Comment: Yes, I cant see my recycler view which is basically everything for this project.

Comment: Somehow the adapter you are linking is null

Comment: You need to add the breakpoints in android studio then debug the app to get the proper flow and the reason why it is null

Comment: gotta learn to use debugger i guess